# problem comparing count($somearray) to zero

Tags: php

my code is pretty straight forward:

```
if(count($votes > 0)) { do something } else { do something else }
```

problem is if the count of that array is 0.. it acts like it was greater than 0.

anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your condition

```
count($votes > 0)
```

should be

```
count($votes) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your parentheses are mismatched.

Try:

```
if( count( $votes ) > 0 ){ do something... } else { do something else }
```

Answer (score 0):

What your are doing

```
count($votes > 0) == count (array() > 0) == count (true) == true
```

What you are looking for:

```
count($votes) > 0
```

You don't want to count the result of the expression `$count > 0`, but you want the count as argument in the expression `$count > 0` (where `$count = count($votes)`)